# How to add a unit test for Wagtail RichText block contents?

Tags: wagtail

I am writing content importers for a Wagtail CMS project. In my importers, I parse strings to a RichText block for a StreamField:

```py
from wagtail.rich_text import RichText

block_content = """<p>Some paragraph</p>"""

block_tuple = (
    "rich_text", 
    RichText(block_content),
)

expected_block_tuple = (
    "rich_text",
    RichText(block_content),
)

assertEqual(
    block_tuple,
    expected_block_tuple
)
```

This unit test is really important to reduce the likelihood of losing data in our import scripts.

However, the assertion fails since the block tuples have different string representations, like the following.

> ('rich_text', <wagtail.rich_text.RichText object at 0x7ff683745b50>)

How can I write an assertion to ensure the output of the parsed RichText block matches an expected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened this as an issue on Wagtail (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/10523) - two `RichText` objects with the same value really ought to compare as equal, but this isn't the case because `RichText` doesn't currently implement an `__eq__` method.

As a workaround for now, you can check the `source` attribute on the two objects for equality:

```py
block_tuple_source = (block_tuple[0], block_tuple[1].source)
expected_block_tuple_source = (expected_block_tuple[0], expected_block_tuple[1].source)
assertEqual(block_tuple_source, expected_block_tuple_source)
```